# How to add 'Pin this program to the taskbar' into jumplist for Windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7, jump-list

I have an application written in .Net 4.0 with WPF. I'm trying to find out how I can add the feature 'Pin this program to the taskbar' that you so often see when you right click a Windows  7 Application icon.

I know that I need to use a jumplist (see: http://www.wpftutorial.net/Jumplists.html) but I haven't been able to find out how to create (or reference) this specific feature.

Comment: By default Windows 7 provides this option right? Why you want to write your own code for that?

Comment: System.Windows.Shell http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.aspx It's in the PresentationFramework.dll assembly

Comment: @Anuraj It's not available for my application. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot and the relevant code?

Comment: What is the type of application you are creating? Please provide more details and possible screenshot too, missing that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is provided by the system, so you don't need to do anything to add it to your application's Jump List. Even if you don't initialize a custom Jump List for your application, it should always be there in the default Jump List that the system uses.

Note that the system seems to be finicky with Jump Lists when running your application in debug mode sometimes (with vshost.exe). If you're not seeing a Jump List you can try restarting the debugger, the IDE or the system, or rebuild your application. However, this should not affect the release executable.

Comment: Hmn. Definitely not there? Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Solved! I was missing my vshost file! Whoops!

Comment: @Michael: Ah, that happens sometimes. I've run into that behavior myself - seems the system quite simply has trouble with vshost.exe and Jump Lists in general.